# Unity 3D OnMouseDrag collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am trying to make a game where you drag different types of spheres and put them together to form a figure (without any gravity). For dragging the objects I use this script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        float distance_to_screen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position).z;
        transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance_to_screen ));

    }

}
```

When I drag two spheres to eachother they go trough eachother. I added a rigibody to the objects, tried a LOT of different things with it, but nothing seemed to work. They always seem to bounce off eachother OR they just don't collide at all. Any sollution to this? Imagine this like a person running in to a wall. The person doesn't bounce off the wall, he just stops moving.

Comment: Change rigidbodies to kinetic?

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka I have tried that out, they were floating all in the air.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why you're getting some strange behaviour (objects clipping through/ignoring each other) is that you're setting `transform.position` directly, rather than manipulating the `Rigidbody` component of the object. Use `Rigidbody.MovePosition()` to also take into account physics when positioning an object.

Now, seeing objects bounce off each other is not an abnormal physics behaviour - this is because when objects clip into each other (as they will often do with your code), they exert a repulsing force on each other (a bit like Newton's third law). If you want to freeze them as soon as they collide, try setting `Rigidbody.isKinematic = true` in the `OnCollisionEnter()` event.

Bringing this all together, your class might look like:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        // Store reference to attached Rigidbody
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        float distance_to_screen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position).z;

        // Move by Rigidbody rather than transform directly
        rb.MovePosition(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance_to_screen )));
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        // Freeze on collision
        rb.isKinematic = true;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this out when I get home.

Comment: Dragging the objects works perfectly, just like before. Only the collision doesn't work at all. EDIT: Nothing really changed. EDIT2: In the first second when I collide them, it works. Inmediatly after that they go into eachother

Comment: @BelgianWizard Is your intention to completely freeze the object (ie. Ignore all physics and any further mouse dragging) after the initial collision? Or do you still want it to be draggable even after it stops? (If the case is the latter, your implementation will probably have to change significantly.)

Comment: We kind of got it to work, but we still have one little problem. Do you have time to chat in a third-party software like Skype? I can send you my username in private. EDIT: How do I PM?

Comment: @BelgianWizard Sorry, I don't presently have access to something like that. We can use a StackOverflow chat room, though. (There is no PM functionality on this site.)

Comment: Sure, unfortunatly I am not able to create one because I don't have the permission to. You need 100 points :( Can you?

Comment: Yep, here you go: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107971/unity-3d-onmousedrag-collision

Answer (score 0):

When directly giving the position variable coordinates in a non-incremental way, the object is "phasing" into existence at the next location fooling the collision system.

You have to code it by having some sort of other system move the object in incremental ways:

Instead of moving the object directly like this:

position =

position = lerp(oldPosition,new position,Time.deltaTime)

Comment: You can edit your post. Don't continue your answer in the comment section.